# Spring rest redirect controller to another

Tags: java, spring, rest

i currently have this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/behavior/{behaviorId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
private ResponseEntity modifyBehavior(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("behaviorId") String behaviorId, @RequestBody BehaviorDto behaviorDto) {

    if (aptitudeRepository.findById(id) == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    if (aptitudeRepository.findBehaviorById(id, behaviorId) == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } Behavior behavior = new Behavior(behaviorId,behaviorDto.getEn(),behaviorDto.getEs());
    return new ResponseEntity(aptitudeRepository.updateBehaviorById(id, behavior), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

im handling the request in this method as i like, but my coworkers told me that this method (and other *behavior methods* should be in their own **BehaviorController** class.
i moved the methods for **behavior** handling to another class (BehaviorController) and all worked quite as espected. the first methods `/aptitude` and `/aptitude/{id}` were redirected to the **aptitudeController** and the other methods like `/aptitude/{id}/behavior` and `aptitude/{id}/behavior/id` were succesfully redirected to *BehaviorController*, everything nice.

buuuuut now i was told that this methods should be redirected from the **AptitudeController** to the **BehaviorController**. along with their @PathVariables and return the other method return (xD sorry for the bad english)

so it will end something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/behavior/{behaviorId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
private ResponseEntity modifyBehavior(@PathVariable("id") String id,
@PathVariable("behaviorId") String behaviorId, 
@RequestBody BehaviorDto behaviorDto) {

return *somehowMethodRedirecting*?
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you create a bean from AptitudeController of BehaviorController and you can pass your values to BehaviorController. In my experience you can not return to BehaviorController.

you are calling this method using url from the browser. then browser will get response rendering the contents.

Comment: im kinda newb, could you explain what you mean by "create a bean from AptitudeController of BehaviorController" ? sorry xD

Comment: I mean object of BehaviorController